# Triangle Siblings in python

Tags: python

I would like to ask again the help of the Python experts in this forum. The task is to create a program that will return a triangle pattern. However, there must be a siblings.

Sample input:

```
Input an Integer:
9
```

Sample Output:

```
*
**
***
****      *
*****     **
******    ***
*******   ****   *
********  *****  **
********* ****** ***
```

The code that I have so far is:

```
a = int(input("Input a number? "))

k=a/3
t=a-k
y=a-(k*2)

for i in range(a + 1):
    print '*' * i

for i in range(t + 1):
    print '*' * i

for i in range(y + 1):
    print '*' * i
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
Input a number: 12
*
**
***
****
*****   
******
*******
********
*********
**********
***********
************

*
**
***
****
*****   
******
*******
********

*
**
***
****
```

It prints after the first triangle, my goal is to print it beside each triangle..

Comment: What is the rule for making siblings?

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? If so, you will find better help elsewhere. However, if there is a specific problem with your code, please reformulate your question to address that issue.

Comment: what exactly decides how many siblings, and how much smaller they should be?

Comment: I can do it but it prints after the triangle not beside..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

makes your triangles.

```
def make_triangle(size, siblings, step): 
    return [['*' * (i-(step*sib)) + ' ' * ((size-(step*sib)) - ((i-(step*sib)) if (i-(step*sib) > 0) else 0)) for sib in xrange(siblings)] for i in xrange(1, size+1)]
```

output:

```
>>> for i in make_triangle(9,3,3):
    print ''.join(i)


*                        
**                     
***                  
****     *          
*****    **        
******   ***      
*******  ****  *  
******** ***** ** 
******************
```

or you could keep it all in the function and:

```
def make_triangle(size, siblings, step): 
    return '\n'.join([''.join(line) for line in [['*' * (i-(step*sib)) + ' ' * ((size-(step*sib)) - ((i-(step*sib)) if (i-(step*sib) > 0) else 0)) for sib in xrange(siblings)] for i in xrange(1, size+1)]])

>>> print make_triangle(9,3,3)
*                        
**                     
***                  
****     *          
*****    **        
******   ***      
*******  ****  *  
******** ***** ** 
******************
```

and if you want a space between them:

```
def make_triangle(size, siblings, step): 
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in [['*' * (i-(step*sib)) + ' ' * ((size-(step*sib)) - ((i-(step*sib)) if (i-(step*sib) > 0) else 0)) for sib in xrange(siblings)] for i in xrange(1, size+1)]])

>>> print make_triangle(9,3,3)
*                          
**                       
***                    
****      *           
*****     **         
******    ***       
*******   ****   *  
********  *****  ** 
********* ****** ***
```

for fun (and you can see very nice function):

```
>>> print make_triangle(13,5,2)
*                                                                
**                                                           
***           *                                           
****          **                                       
*****         ***         *                          
******        ****        **                       
*******       *****       ***       *             
********      ******      ****      **           
*********     *******     *****     ***     *    
**********    ********    ******    ****    **   
***********   *********   *******   *****   ***  
************  **********  ********  ******  **** 
************* *********** ********* ******* *****
```

and more fun:

```
>>> print make_triangle(13,5,2)[::-1]
***** ******* ********* *********** *************
 ****  ******  ********  **********  ************
  ***   *****   *******   *********   ***********
   **    ****    ******    ********    **********
    *     ***     *****     *******     *********
           **      ****      ******      ********
            *       ***       *****       *******
                     **        ****        ******
                      *         ***         *****
                                 **          ****
                                  *           ***
                                               **
                                                *
```

**addition:** some explanation of how it works:

this is what the code does in more basic form:

```
def make_triangle(size, siblings, step): 
    out_list = []
    for i in xrange(1, size+1):
        in_list = []
        for sib in xrange(siblings):
            if i-(step*sib) > 0: 
                in_list.append('*' * (i-(step*sib)) + ' ' * ((size-(step*sib)) - (i-(step*sib))))
            else:
                in_list.append('*' * (i-(step*sib)) + ' ' * (size-(step*sib))
        out_list.append(in_list)
    line_list = []
    for in_list in out_list:
        line_list.append(' '.join(in_list))
    result = '\n'.join(line_list)
    return result
```

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't get the code above as I am really new to python...I however, edited my post as I am able to make the siblings but I can't print it out beside each other, it is always after, is there any way to make use of join to make the triangles print beside each other?

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you but I make use of your code:
    a = int(input("Input a number? "))

    k=a/3 
    t=a-k
    y=a-(k*2)

    print '\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in [['*' * (i-(y*sib)) + ' ' * (a-i) for sib in xrange(t)] for i in xrange(1, a+1)]])

And it works fine, however,I can't understand this line:

    print '\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in [['*' * (i-(y*sib)) + ' ' * (a-i) for sib in xrange(t)] for i in xrange(1, a+1)]])

Comment: @AilenSamsonLaguda hi, im glad my code is working for you, but im sorry that i cannot help explain it to you at the moment, the functions involved are all pretty basic, only putting them together in a complex way. i suggest if you are so new to python you should either accept that you dont understand the code and use it as "magic" or learn python and try to understand it yourself. but - i will put up a small information on what exactly the code is doing.... good luck.